# How to come true the convolution with a 2-D array in frequency domain with python

Tags: fft, lowpass-filter, image-processing

I use the pretty simple example used in many books to understand the convolution in the frequency domain. But I cannot find the real results.

```
import numpy as np

img = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
kernel = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                   [0, 1, 2, 3, 0],
                   [0, 4, 5, 6, 0],
                   [0, 7, 8, 9, 0],
                   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

fft_img = np.fft.fft2(img)
fft_kernel = np.fft.fft2(kernel)

fshift = (fft_img* fft_kernel)  # Convelution theory at frequency domain

img_back = np.fft.ifft2(fshift)

img_back = np.real(img_back)
img_back = img_back.astype(np.int)

print(img_back)
```

The output of the img_back is

```
[[9 0 0 7 8]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [3 0 0 0 1]
 [6 0 0 4 5]]
```

However, the answer should be

```
[[0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 9 8 7 0]
 [0 6 5 4 0]
 [0 3 2 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

So, is there someone who can help me? I don't know the reason why. And how to come true the ideal result?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the identity for the convolution is

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

You get the correct result by replacing

```
img_back = np.real(img_back)
```

by

```
img_back = np.fft.ifftshift(np.round(np.real(img_back)))
```

It is important to `np.round` (to the nearest integer) before casting to `np.int`, otherwise you will may have wrong results due to rounding errors e.g. `np.array([0.999999999999]).astype(np.int) = 0`

### Notes about fftshift

The the fftshift and ifftshift operations are equivalent to a convolution, we could express `fftshift(X)` as $S * X$.
Convolutions are commutative and associative $a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c$, and $a * b = b * a$, it is immediate in the frequency from the multiplication operator properties.

Lets say $X$ is your image $H$ is your kernel

you can check that $S^{-1} * X$, or $X = S$, is precisely the term that I mentioned in the beginning of the answer is the identity for the convolution

What you have from my solution above is $S^{-1} * (H * X)$, the solution you metioned in the comments is $H * (S^{-1} * X)$, and there would be one other variation $(S^{-1} * H) * X$ that would represents calling fftshift on the kernel instead of the image. I already saw some doing ffthisft in both inputs and then ifftshift to the output.

Alternative forms...

$(S^{-1} * X) * H = X * (S^{-1} * H) = S * (S^{-1} * X) * (S^{-1} * H)$

Comment: Thank you very much. I found when I insert the code `img = np.fft.ifftshift(img)` before `fft_kernel = np.fft.fft2(img)`, this also can get the same result. But I still don't understand what you said about the impulse identify for the convolution.

Comment: updated the answer explaining this case

Comment: Thank you very much. It is really clear. But I still don't understand what you said about the impulse identify for the convolution, or I should ask why we need an `ifftshift(X)` for this operation. You know there is not `fftshift(X)`.

Comment: If thinking about circular shifting of negative indices is not helping, think about two signals starting at with duration N/2, centered at N/2, it means they have non-zero values from N/4 to 3N/4. once you convolve them the result will be possibly non-zero in the range N/2 to 3N/2, but you compute the FFT using only N samples, you assign the interval N/2 to 3N/2, to the indices 0 to N. This is why we use `fftshift`.

Comment: Thake a look at this answer in the 1D context, it includes plots that may help to build your intuition https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/73471/circular-wrapping-of-an-asymmetric-function-in-dft-calculations/73475#73475

Comment: Thank you very much. You help me understand this too much.

Comment: Please check here how to proceed when an answer solves your problem or simply is was useful (even if not your question) https://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: OKAY. Thank you for your guide.